# Writing CSV file using Spark and scala - empty quotes instead of Null values

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I'm using spark 2.4.1 and scala,
and trying to write DF to csv file.
it seems that in case of null values ,the csv contains "".
Is it possible to remove those empty quotes?

```
 val data = Seq(
      Row(1, "a"),
      Row(5, "z"),
      Row(5, null)
    )

    val schema = StructType(
      List(
        StructField("num", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("letter", StringType, true)
      )
    )

    var df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
      schema
    )
  df.write.csv("location/")
```

The output seems like:

```
1,a
5,z
5,""
```

And I want it will be:

```
1,a
5,z
5,
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use options of the writer see [CSV](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) specific options(SaveMode is not related to answer);

```
 df.write
   .option("nullValue", null)
   .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
   .csv("location/")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df.write.option("nullValue",None).save("location/")
```

Comment: Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098) as it makes your answer more helpful to future readers in general. In particular, it'd be great if you extend this answer with an explanation why this solution is a better approach than the one given in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312905/5698098). See also the [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.