# Replace Null values with no value in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am writing a csv file onto datalake from a dataframe which has null values. Spark sql explicitly puts the value as `Null` for null values. I want to replace these null values with no values or no other strings.

When i write the csv file from databricks, it looks like this

```
ColA,ColB,ColC 
null,ABC,123     
ffgg,DEF,345    
null,XYZ,789
```

I tried replacing nulls with `''` using `fill.na`, but when I do that, the file gets written like this

```
ColA,ColB,ColC    
'',ABC,123     
ffgg,DEF,345    
'',XYZ,789
```

And I want my csv file to look like this. How do I achieve this from spark sql. I am using databricks. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

```
ColA,ColB,ColC    
,ABC,123     
ffg,DEF,345    
,XYZ,789
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing CSV file using Spark and scala - empty quotes instead of Null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312569/writing-csv-file-using-spark-and-scala-empty-quotes-instead-of-null-values)

Comment: **`option("nullValue", null)`** won't work if your `first field` is null still keeps as **`""`**

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to use **`.saveAsTextFile`** for this case instead of `csv`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
//+----+----+----+
//|col1|col2|col3|
//+----+----+----+
//|null| ABC| 123|
//|  dd| ABC| 123|
//+----+----+----+

//extract header from dataframe
val header=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(df.columns.mkString(",")))

//union header with data and replace [|]|null then save
header.union(df.rdd.map(x => x.toString)).map(x => x.replaceAll("[\\[|\\]|null]","")).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("<path>")

//content of file
//co1,co2,co3
//,ABC,123
//dd,ABC,123
```

---

If **`First field`** in your data is **`not null`** then you can use `csv` option:

```
 df.write.option("nullValue", null).mode("overwrite").csv("<path>")
```

Comment: Thanks much. This helped a lot